# When using ResponsiveSlides plugin, 'Image links' don't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

This all works perfectly in Firefox and IE, however it won't work in Chrome unless i right click and goto inspect element and as soon as i close inspect element it goes back to not working with just an arrow cursor when hovered over as if it's not even a link.

I tried setting its container to the highest z-index, i've tried pointer-events: all; with none; on the parent and without etc.. to no avail.

It's extremely confusing as i usually don't have these sorts of issues with chrome alone.

```
<div class="top_box3">
  <div class="rslides" id="slider2">

    <!-- Problem image link in chrome -->
    <a href="mailto:test@test.com"><img src="images/info_slidebox3.jpg" width="420" height="240" alt=""/></a>

    <img src="images/info_slidebox1.jpg" width="415" height="240" alt=""/>
    <img src="images/info_slidebox2.jpg" width="415" height="240" alt=""/>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS code:**

```
.top_box3 {

    -moz-background-clip: padding;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
    background-clip: padding-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #666666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #666666;

    width: 420px;
    height: 240px;

    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 67px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
        maxwidth: 420,
        maxheight: 240,
        speed: 800,
        timeout: 4000
    });
});
```

Hopefully someone can share some insight,

Si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i solved the problem, it's very strange as I've never seen this before.

I inspected the code and found no discrepancies, which made me even more confused, eventually i thought to my self something has to be overlapping my image that i didn't specifically set because i'd put links further down the page and they weren't clickable in Chrome either, so it was almost like the whole page was covered somehow.

After tearing my hair out i decided to add the below code to my css just as a long shot.

```
body {
    /*existing*/
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /*what i added*/
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

This fixed the problem and it only occurred in Google Chrome, apparently the body was overlapping my divs and scaled with the window size, i haven't figured out how or where the code is that was doing this yet but forcing the height and width to 0px fixed it.

I have to say I've never ran into this problem before with any websites I've created.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the image inside a  element is floated. So probably if you inspect the  element with your developer tool and inspect it, it will tell you that the element is 0px height and 0px width.

You can ty add the following css:

```
.rslides a {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;   
}
```

With the display: block, the a will fill the complete width of the parent container. 
Extra: use   overflow: hidden;  The overflow: hidden will give the a element height, because the floated  will push the bottom of the  down. Or set the height and width for

Comment: I already tried messing with that and it didn't fix problem at all, it's obviously an issue with Chrome alone as everything works correctly in IE and FF, possibly a synax in the css that chrome doesnt accept or works differently. Anyone have any other insights?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brutusmaximus/Wn8h9/3/ Its work in the jsfiddle. Maybe there is some other html overlaying your slider.